# Convert string to multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem managing some data that are saved in a really awful format.

I have [data for points](https://filebin.net/mfqrxtphkno5kbw0) that correspond to the edges of a polygon. The data for each polygon is separated by the string `>`, while the `x` and `y` values for the points are separated with non-unified criteria, sometimes with a number of spaces, sometimes with some spaces and a tabulation. I've tried to load such data to an array of arrays with the following code:

```py
f = open('/Path/Data.lb','r')
data = f.read()
splat = data.split('>')

region = []

for number, polygon in enumerate(splat[1:len(splat)], 1):
    region.append(float(polygon))
```

But I keep getting an error trying to run the `float()` function (I've cut it as it's much longer):

```py
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\n     -73.311      -48.328\n     -73.311      -48.326\n     -73.318      -48.321\n     ...
...     -73.324\t  -48.353\n     -73.315\t  -48.344\n     -73.313\t  -48.337\n'
```

Is there a way to convert the data to float without modifying the source file? If not, is there a way to easily modify the source file so that all columns are separated the same way? I guess that way the same code should run smoothly.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file?

Comment: Have you tried using regex to retrieve the numbers? As not_speshal mentioned, a sample would give better context with what you're dealing with.

Comment: @rm-fme I have not tried that, no. How would I use regex in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @Feva - What is the trailing 0 from lines 4292 onwards (eg. -73.8514690865358 -46.69748323908008 0)

Comment: @not_speshal I guess it's formatted that way to plot in case the program used needs height as well as lat/lon, but it has no information that I need

Comment: The python function `float` can convert a string into **one** float number.  Your string has a bunch of number like strings separated by a mix of characters.  One way or other, using python string methods, you need to split it into a list of single-number strings.  From there to a list or numeric array is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("PataIce.lb", "r") as file:
    polygons = file.read().strip(">").strip().split(">")
    
region =[]
for polygon in polygons:
    sides = polygon.strip().split("\n")
    points = [[float(num) for num in side.split()[:2]] for side in sides]
    region.append(points)
```

Some of the points contain more than 2 values and I've restricted the script to only read the first two numbers in these cases.

Comment: This one solved it for me. I did add the line points=np.vstack(points) before appending, as I needed to iterate through each subarray and didn't know how to do it without that conversion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match decimal numbers.

```
import re
PATH = <path_to_file>
coords = []
with open(PATH) as f:
    for line in f:
        nums = re.findall('-?\d+\.\d+', line)
        if len(nums) >0:
            coords.append(nums)
print(coords)
```

**Note:** this solution ignores the trailing 0 at the end of some lines.
Be aware that the results in `coords` are still strings. You'll need to convert them to float using `float()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [79]: astr = '\n     -73.311      -48.328\n     -73.311      -48.326\n     -73.318      -48.321\n  -73.324\
    ...: t  -48.353\n     -73.315\t  -48.344\n     -73.313\t  -48.337\n'
In [80]: lines =astr.splitlines()
In [81]: lines
Out[81]: 
['',
 '     -73.311      -48.328',
 '     -73.311      -48.326',
 '     -73.318      -48.321',
 '  -73.324\t  -48.353',
 '     -73.315\t  -48.344',
 '     -73.313\t  -48.337']
```

`splitlines` deals with the `\n` separator; `split()` handles the tab and spaces.

```
In [82]: [line.split() for line in lines]
Out[82]: 
[[],
 ['-73.311', '-48.328'],
 ['-73.311', '-48.326'],
 ['-73.318', '-48.321'],
 ['-73.324', '-48.353'],
 ['-73.315', '-48.344'],
 ['-73.313', '-48.337']]
```

The initial `[]` needs to be removed one way or other:

```
In [84]: np.array(Out[82][1:], dtype=float)
Out[84]: 
array([[-73.311, -48.328],
       [-73.311, -48.326],
       [-73.318, -48.321],
       [-73.324, -48.353],
       [-73.315, -48.344],
       [-73.313, -48.337]])
```

This works only if each `line` has the same number of elements, where 2.  As long as the lists of strings in `Out[82]` is clean enough you can let `np.array` do the conversion from string to float.

Your actually file may require some further handling, but this should give you an idea of the basics.